# Detect out of stock with Python in Retail Scanning data

Tags: python, stock, inventory, scanning

I'm receiving shop scanning machine data. And thank to this I'm trying to detect out of stock with Python.

Here 2 cases : One high sold product and one low sold product.

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║ Product ║    Date    ║ Quantity ║ Status ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║ A       ║ 01/01/2018 ║       57 ║ ok     ║
║ A       ║ 02/01/2018 ║       79 ║ ok     ║
║ A       ║ 03/01/2018 ║       95 ║ ok     ║
║ A       ║ 04/01/2018 ║       81 ║ ok     ║
║ A       ║ 05/01/2018 ║       10 ║ ok     ║
║ A       ║ 06/01/2018 ║        5 ║ ok     ║
║ A       ║ 07/01/2018 ║        0 ║ oos    ║
║ A       ║ 08/01/2018 ║        0 ║ oos    ║
║ A       ║ 09/01/2018 ║        0 ║ oos    ║
║ A       ║ 10/01/2018 ║        0 ║ oos    ║
║ A       ║ 11/01/2018 ║       84 ║ ok     ║
║ A       ║ 12/01/2018 ║       37 ║ ok     ║
║ A       ║ 13/01/2018 ║       45 ║ ok     ║
║ A       ║ 14/01/2018 ║       50 ║ ok     ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

and

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║ Product ║    Date    ║ Quantity ║ Status ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║ B       ║ 01/01/2018 ║        1 ║ ok     ║
║ B       ║ 02/01/2018 ║        0 ║ ok     ║
║ B       ║ 03/01/2018 ║        1 ║ ok     ║
║ B       ║ 04/01/2018 ║        3 ║ ok     ║
║ B       ║ 05/01/2018 ║        0 ║ ok     ║
║ B       ║ 06/01/2018 ║        1 ║ ok     ║
║ B       ║ 07/01/2018 ║        0 ║ ok     ║
║ B       ║ 08/01/2018 ║        0 ║ oos    ║
║ B       ║ 09/01/2018 ║        0 ║ oos    ║
║ B       ║ 10/01/2018 ║        0 ║ oos    ║
║ B       ║ 11/01/2018 ║        1 ║ ok     ║
║ B       ║ 12/01/2018 ║        2 ║ ok     ║
║ B       ║ 13/01/2018 ║        0 ║ ok     ║
║ B       ║ 14/01/2018 ║        1 ║ ok     ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

The status show out of stock that should be detected, and with millions of records i'm using python to manipulate those data.

Is there any module / library / way to detect it with python, even for low sold product (it's not just saying that 0 sells=out of stock, just some product are not bought every day)

Comment: use pandas dataframes and you can filter for `Quantity == 0` [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Comment: it's working for high sold products, but for low it's not possible as they're not sold everyday.

Comment: do you have an example code ? I'm guessing you dont calculate status you just look for 'oos' or are you trying to calculate based on quantity sold if the product is oos or not ?